# Hide the breakpoints-bar in Jetbrains PHPStorm 4

Tags: phpstorm

I recently upgraded and bought a new license for PHPStorm 4 and I never noticed but now there is an irritating breakpoints-bar in PHPStorm and I really want to hide it but I can't find how.

Is there anyone who knows how to do it (on OSX 10.7 Lion)?
Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bar also shows some useful information like bookmarks, icons for the overridden methods, СSS colors. There is no way to hide it.